# How many different scores are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A TV game show has a format in which contestant are asked questions and give answers .Each contestant start with the score of zero points. A contestant's score is then calculated as follows after giving a correct answer the score is increased by one after a wrong answer the score is divided by 2 if a contestant response to each questions how many different scores are possible?

so far I am able to think like this Encode the contestant's responses by a word $a=a_1 a_2 \ldots a_n$, where $a_k=R$ if the $k$ th question is answered correctly, and $a_k=W$ otherwise. For any words $a$ and $b$, we claim that the words $a R R W b$ and $W a W R b$ have the same length and yield the same score for the contestants. To see this, suppose that the word $a$ yields score $x$. Then $a R R W$ yields $\frac{x+2}{2}$, while $W a W R$ yields $\frac{x}{2}+1$; this proves the claim.

Comment: What does "if a contestant response to each questions" mean? Did you mean to specify the number of questions? A good way to start is to work out small examples: if there are 2 questions then what scores are possible? Is there any score that can be achieved in more than one way?

Comment: @AnneBauval please look at the new question!

Comment: Well done! Now you can use your remark to restrict to words of the form $RW^pRW^qRW^r\dots RW^tR^n$ where $p,q,r,\dots,t\ge1$ and $n\ge0.$

Comment: @AnneBauval can you elaborate it further?

Comment: Initial $W$'s can be forgotten, and recursively, every $RRW$ in your word can be simplified to $WR.$

Comment: I wonder why the question was closed. The OP added an important step towards the solution. I vote for its reopening.

Comment: How many problems are there? $n$?

Comment: yes n problems.